# IF, OR, AND struggles

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've written the following, but it comes back with the formula is missing an opening or closing parenthesis. Is someone able to help correct where I'm going wrong. I'm basically trying to create a spreadsheet for a sales team that will calculate what commission they will earn based on a number of meetings they book. But there are different levels of commission to the number of meetings.

```
=IF(OR(G23<=4,G23*M9,OR(G23>=5,G23<=7,G23*M10,OR(G23>8,G23<=9,G23*M13,OR(G23>=10,G23*M15))))
```

I had got it working on 2, but anything past that and its spitting its dummy out :(

Please help!

Thanks

Jess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH to return the relative match to a CHOOSE that will return the correct Cell:

```
=G23 * CHOOSE(MATCH(G23,{0,5,8,10}),M9,M10,M13,M15)
```

If you want to stick with the IF, realize the IFs resolve in squence, so the OR is not needed:

```
= G23 * IF(G23<=4,M9,IF(G23<=7,M10,IF(G23<=9,M13,M15)))
```

[image]

But the issue with your formula is that OR returns a Boolean and you must nest the if:

```
=IF(G23<=4,G3*M9,IF(OR(G23>=5,G23<=7),G23*M10,IF(OR(G23>=8,G23<=9),G23*M13,G23*M15)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Scott. Would it be worth me sharing my spreadsheet?

Comment: Only if this did not work.  Because if one of these did not work for you then I am misunderstanding the request.

Comment: So the one you gave me (second one), worked but it missed out my final criteria, so I tried adding it based on what you wrote and its not working now :( otherwise it worked great!

Comment: Please post the one you tried that did not work

Comment: You should not need to add the `G23>=10` test as that is assumed.  Anything greater than 9 will return the value in M15.

Comment: oh it didn't work as the value remained the same, I'll try it again though

Comment: Tried it again and changed the number of meetings to 11 and it was still calculating at the rate for 8-9 meetings which is M13

Comment: What are the values in M13 and M15?

Comment: They and 20 and 25 :)

Comment: works for me @jess see edit

Comment: I have got it working now too :) Thank you so much for your help Scott, I've literally spent all day putting two fingers up to it :D

Comment: @Jess please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer